# Why Spark execution memory should be 1.5 times of reserved memory?

Tags: apache-spark

Why Spark execution memory should be 1.5 times of reserved memory?

I have gone through multiple spark articles like : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/apache-spark-memory-management-deep-dive-deepak-rajak/?articleId=6673917764203360256

But didn't find any clear detail why is it so?

Comment: Are you referring to this part of the post: 

```For your information, if you don’t give Spark executor at least 1.5 * Reserved Memory = 450MB heap, it will fail with “please use larger heap size” error message.```

Comment: I read that statement , then my query was why Spark has this condition?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer with reasons as explained below.

#### Limits Hardcoded In Source Code

The value of `1.5` times mentioned in the article is based on how Spark checks the executor memory when running.

This check is done in the source-code of the `UnifiedMemoryManager.scala` class.

See [this link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/memory/UnifiedMemoryManager.scala#L217) for the source code on github. The relevant code is:

```
val minSystemMemory = (reservedMemory * 1.5).ceil.toLong
:
:
val executorMemory = conf.getSizeAsBytes(config.EXECUTOR_MEMORY.key)
if (executorMemory < minSystemMemory) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Executor memory $executorMemory must be at least $minSystemMemory...")
}
:
:
```

As can be seen, if `executorMemory < minSystemMemory`, the application will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

The `minSystemMemory` is set to `1.5 * reservedMemory`. So that's what the article is referring to.

#### Why The Value Of 1.5?

There isn't any explicit documentation in the code explaining why the value of `1.5` times reserved memory (`1.5` is a magic number) was chosen. So we will have to ask the contributor to this code to really know. Here's hoping she/he sees this and responds :)

#### An Educated Guess

But here is an educated guess - spark needs executors to be at least `450mb` to  claim, at minimum, the default `reserved memory` size of `300mb` from the executor. As the article mentions, this is needed to run spark successfully. So an executor of `1` times the default `reserved memory of 300 mb` doesn't make sense (there will be no memory left for `user` and `storage and execution`. An executor of `1.5` times can accommodate this requirement for spark and run successfully.

But they could have gone for a higher value, no? My thinking here is that a higher value will prevent developers from running spark applications on local machines, where the executor and driver share the same JVM.

To ensure those who want to run spark in smaller JVMs (for example, a JVM of 1g, which is a common JVM heap size), having the executor sized so that it can accommodate the reserved memory claim of `300mb` and also the driver and executors is prudent. To this end, a value of `1.5` times reserved was chosen, which brings the minimum executor size to `450mb` to accommodate the runs of spark applications on local.